# I'm getting `needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` with scrapy selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using scrapy with selenium the code is:

```
    import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from  selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which


class GoldendataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'goldendata'
    allowed_domains = ['www.golden.com']
    #start_urls = ['https://golden.com/wiki/Cluster%3A_COVID-19-ZXJX9AR/']

    def __init__(self):

        chrome_options= Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


        chrome_path=which('chromedriver')

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options=chrome_options)
        driver.get("https://golden.com/wiki/Cluster%3A_COVID-19-ZXJX9AR/")



        self.html = driver.page_source

        driver.close()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2020-05-02 10:11:35 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2020-05-02 10:19:16 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "F:\Git Contribution\Fightpandemic\Scrpers\golden\golden\spiders\goldendata.py", line 22, in 
 __init__
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I tried installing pywin32 and updating py and selenium but it doesn't do anything..
so how could I solve this error I tried most of the things i know and i also searched for github issues and stack overflow but didn't found anything.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `arg` is `None`. Where does `arg` from `goldendata.py` come from? Maybe an argument that your spider needs that you forgot to pass?

Comment: Maybe you need to change `(" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg` to `not arg or (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg)`. Make sure you are not hiding an issue, though, the logic seems specific to your spider.

Answer (score 0):

You use `which('chromedriver')` to get the path for chromedriver, but it seems that `which` returns `None` because chromedriver is not in PATH.

You could use relative path for `chrome_path` in your script.  Or, add *chromedriver.exe* to PATH.

Comment: it's not the case